# Find $\vec{B}$ given $\vec{F}$ and $\vec{v}$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, vectors

Given a charged particle moving through a uniform magnetic field, is it possible to determine the magnetic field vector given only the particle's initial velocity and the force it experiences?

I'm assuming the following formula

$\vec{F}=q\,\,\vec{v}\times\vec{B}$

However, I haven't been able to find $\vec{B}$ even when given $\vec{F}$, $q$, and $\vec{v}$.

Comment: I very much doubt that this arose out of a homework question, seeing as it's actually unsolvable. There are interesting physical and mathematical reasons why not, so I'm voting to reopen.

Comment: @MarkH: Note that the site's definition of homework encompasses a broader term than "assigned by a professor" (as evident in the link in the close banner). it seems to me that this question falls under the category of *homework* under our definition.

Comment: @KyleKanos Does the edited question fit the non-homework criteria?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's not enough information to solve for the field. There are infinite $\vec{B}$ fields that satisfy the equation. First, write the field as
$$\vec{B} = \vec{B}_v + \vec{B}_p$$
where $\vec{B}_v$ is the component of the field parallel to the particle's velocity and $\vec{B}_p$ is the component perpendicular to it. Then,
\begin{align}
\vec{F} &= q\vec{v} \times \vec{B} \\
\vec{F} &= q\vec{v} \times (\vec{B}_v + \vec{B}_p) \\
\vec{F} &= q(\vec{v} \times \vec{B}_v + \vec{v} \times \vec{B}_p) \\
\vec{F} &= q\vec{v} \times \vec{B}_p \\
\end{align}
Notice that $\vec{B}_v$ dropped out of the equation since the cross product of parallel vectors is the zero vector. That means it has no effect on the force, meaning it can be anything.

You can learn the magnitude of the magnetic field component that's perpendicular to the particle's velocity
$$F = qvB_p \implies B_p = \frac{F}{qv}$$
and you can learn the direction from the right-hand rule. But, that's all that can be calculated. The most general solution will be of the form
$$\vec{B} = \alpha\vec{B}_v + \vec{B}_p$$
where $\alpha$ is any real number.

Comment: There is enough information to solve for $\vec{B}$. Set up the cross product in $\vec{F}=q\vec{v}\times\vec{B}$ as a determinant and then solve for each field component individually.

Comment: @Bob, Mark is right. The determinant is linear, and therefore, if you do it like that, you'd see this exact statement there, as a determinant with two linear dependent rows is zero.

Answer (score 0):

Write in matrix form:

\begin{align}\vec{F}&=q \vec{v}\times \vec{B}\notag\\
&=q\det \begin{pmatrix} \hat{i}& \hat{j} &\hat{k} \\ v_i & v_j & v_k \\ B_i& B_j & B_k \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

Perform the determinant and equate the components of the l.h.s. with the r.h.s. For example,

$$F_x = q (v_jB_k-v_k B_j)$$

The rest is calculation.

Comment: Try the calculation. It won't work. All of the magnetic field terms will cancel out.